# How to show $\frac{1}{L}\|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|_2^2 \leq \langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) ,y-x \rangle$ for strongly convex function?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a strongly convex function, i.e.,

$$
\langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) ,y-x \rangle \geq \theta \|y-x\|_2^2 \,\,\,\,\, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$

or

$$
z^T(\nabla^2 f(x) -\theta I)z\geq 0 \,\,\,\,\forall  z \neq 0
$$

Also, suppose $\nabla f(x)$ is a Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L>0$, i.e., $ \|\nabla f(y)- \nabla f(x)\|_2  \leq L \|y-x\|_2$.

> Show $\frac{1}{L}\|\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\|_2^2 \leq \langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) ,y-x \rangle$

Comment: Your statement is definitely wrong. Just suppose $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2$, then $L=1$ and the right side should be $(x-y)^2$. However, the left side is $\frac{1}{4}|y^4-x^4|$. It is clear that this inequality can't hold.

Comment: To know about the proof of some properties of strongly convex function, I recommend the book "Lecture on Convex Optimization" of Nesterov.

Comment: @foxell: Thank you for your careful reading. I had dropped $\nabla$ in the left hand side. By the way, your left hand side becomes $(y^2-x^2)$ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get the conclusion we only need the convexity of $f(x)$ rather than the strong convexity. It is easy to show that if $\nabla f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $L$ then we have:$$f(y)-f(x)-\langle\nabla f(x),y-x\rangle\leq\frac{L}{2}\| x-y\|^2$$
To show this inequality, we have:\begin{align}
f(y)-f(x)-\langle\nabla f(x),y-x\rangle&=\int_{0}^{1}\langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x)),y-x \rangle dt-\langle\nabla f(x),y-x\rangle \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x))-\nabla f(x),y-x \rangle dt \\
&\leq\int_0^1\|\nabla f(x+t(y-x))-\nabla f(x)\|\|y-x\| dt\\
&\leq\int_0^1Lt\|y-x \|^2dt=\frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2
\end{align}

In order to get the result we need to consider the next function $$h(x)=f(x)-\langle \nabla f(y),x\rangle$$
It is clear that $h(x)$ is convex and also $\nabla h(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $L$, and hence $y\in\arg\min_{x}h(x)$ because $\nabla h(y)=0$. We have:$$ h(x-\frac{1}{L}\nabla h(x))\geq h(y) $$
Use the first inequality:
$$ h(x-\frac{1}{L}\nabla h(x))\leq h(x)-\frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla h(x)\|^2   $$
We have:
$$ h(y)\leq h(x)-\frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla h(x) \|^2 $$
$$f(y)+\langle\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle\leq f(x)-\frac{1}{2L}\| \nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|^2  $$
$$f(y)-f(x)+\langle\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle\leq -\frac{1}{2L}\| \nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|^2$$
 Exchange $x,y$:
$$f(x)-f(y)+\langle\nabla f(x),y-x\rangle\leq -\frac{1}{2L}\| \nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|^2$$
Add them together then you can get the conclusion.

Comment: Could you show me how you get the first line? Also, why $h(x-\frac{1}{L}\nabla h(x)) \geq h(y)$?

Comment: Ok, I have given the proof of the first line now. And the answer to your second question is that as I said $y$ is the global minimum of $h(x)$ so $h(y)\leq h(z),\forall z\in R^n$

Comment: It was beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

By definition of strong convexity we have the following:

\begin{equation}
f(x) \geq f(y) + <\nabla f(y), x-y> + \frac{\sigma}{2} \left\lVert x-y\right\rVert^2
\end{equation}

Similarly we have:

\begin{equation}
f(y) \geq f(x) + <\nabla f(x), y-x> + \frac{\sigma}{2} \left\lVert x-y\right\rVert^2
\end{equation}

If you sum up these two inequalities and organize them you will end up with the following:

\begin{equation}
<\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x), y-x>  \geq  \sigma.\left\lVert x-y\right\rVert^2
\end{equation}

Which is what you have. We call this function $\sigma$-strongly convex. To give an example, "negative entropy" is a 1-strongly convex (also known as 1-SC) function wrt L1-norm which is used as regularization term for making a non-smooth function smooth in L1-setting (in learning with experts setup)--Please note that in L1-setting everything is a simplex.

Additionally, you can use ["Hölder's inequality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) to prove the general case shown below (not just norm 2):

\begin{equation}
\left\lVert \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)\right\rVert_{\infty}  \left\lVert x-y \right\rVert_{1}  \geq <\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y), x-y> \geq  \sigma.\left\lVert x-y\right\rVert_{1}^2
\end{equation}

[image]

Comment: What I have is not what you have. My lower bound is in terms of $\nabla f(x)$ and $\nabla f(y)$ while yours is in terms of $\|x-y\|^2$. Please correct your derivation.