# Convex function inequality with eigenvalues of Hessian matrix are bounded above and away from zero

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, convexity-inequality

1. We have a twice continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu,L>0$ constants
2. We have $\mu\cdot E\preccurlyeq\nabla^2f(x)\preccurlyeq L\cdot E$. that means that the eigenvalues are bounded above and away from zero (E is the identity matrix)
3. We have that $f$ is convex

Now we want to show:

$(\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^T\cdot(x-y)\geq\frac{1}{L}||\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)||^2$

Comment: A solution here, albeit I don't think it is as clear as it could be https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3214039/27978.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the co-coercivity of the gradient.

The following is inspired/stolen from these wonderful [notes](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf) of Vandenberghe.

Suppose $g$ is convex, $L$ Lipschitz smooth and has a minimiser $y^*$.
Note that for any $x$ $g(y) \le g(x) + \langle \nabla g(x), y-x \rangle +{L \over 2} \|y-x\|^2$, and minimising both sides gives
$g(y^*) \le g(x)-{1 \over 2L} \| \nabla g(x) \|^2$ (a lower bound on the 'cost to go').

Now pick some $y$ and define $\phi(x) = f(x)-\langle \nabla f(y),x \rangle $, note that $\phi$ is convex, $L$ Lipschitz smooth and has a minimiser at $x=y$ (since $\nabla \phi(y) = 0$). Hence
$\phi(x)-\phi(y) \ge {1 \over 2L} \| \nabla \phi(x) \|^2$ and unraveling gives
$f(x)-f(y) - \langle \nabla f(y), x-y \rangle \ge {1 \over 2L} \| \nabla f(x) -\nabla f (y)\|^2 $.

Exchanging the roles of $x,y$ gives
$f(y)-f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle \ge {1 \over 2L} \| \nabla f(x) -\nabla f (y)\|^2 $ and adding yields
$\langle \nabla f(x) -  \nabla f(y), x-y \rangle \ge {1 \over L} \| \nabla f(x) -\nabla f (y)\|^2 $