# Smoothness inequality over three points

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions, convex-geometry

A few years ago, I had taken note that if a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ has Lipschitz continuous gradient $\nabla f(x)$ with modulus $L$, then $$\langle \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2), x_2 - x_3\rangle \leq \frac{L}{4}||x_1 - x_3||_2^2$$ for any $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb{R}^n$. How can I prove this inequality? Also, is it possible to obtain a lower bound to the inner product in terms of distance $||x_1 - x_3||_2^2$ if the function is also $m$-strongly convex?

Edit: when $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}||x||^2$, the inequality holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mvkbr's post, I tried to find the book cited by Antipin, but I could not find an English version. Then, I looked at a few other books by Russian scholars and finally found the answer in Section 7.2.1 of Polyak's Introduction to Optimization. I share the proof for completeness.

The proof is based on the co-coercivity of gradient:
\begin{align}
\langle \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2),\ x_3 - x_2\rangle &= \langle \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2),\ x_1 - x_2\rangle + \langle \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2),\ x_3 - x_1\rangle
\\
&\geq \frac{1}{L}||\nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2||^2 + \langle \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2),\ x_3 - x_1\rangle
\\
&\geq -\frac{L}{4}||x_3 - x_1||^2
\end{align}
where the second inequality follows from the identity
$$
||a||^2 + \langle a,\ b\rangle \geq -\frac{1}{4}||b||^2 \qquad \forall a,b.
$$
Negating both sides completes the proof.

If the function is also strongly convex with modulus $m$, then one can also obtain
$$
\langle \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2),\ x_2 - x_3\rangle \leq \frac{1}{4m}||\nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_3)||^2
$$
using a similar proof technique.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is convex, we have the following inequalities
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla f(x_1)(x_2-x_1) & \le f(x_2) - f(x_1),\\
\nabla f(x_2)(x_3-x_2) & \le f(x_3) - f(x_2),\\
\nabla f(x_3)(x_1-x_3) & \le f(x_1) - f(x_3).
\end{aligned}
$$
Adding them results in
$$
\nabla f(x_1)(x_2-x_1) + \nabla f(x_2)(x_3-x_2) + \nabla f(x_3)(x_1-x_3)\le 0.
$$
So that
$$
( \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2) ) (x_2-x_3)
\le \nabla f(x_1)(x_1-x_3) -\nabla f(x_3)(x_1-x_3) \le L \|x_1-x_3\|^2.
$$
Which is not quite the desired inequality.

---

Since the gradient is Lipschitz, we have the following stronger inequalities:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla f(x_1)(x_2-x_1) 
+ \frac1{2L} \|\nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2)\|^2
& \le f(x_2) - f(x_1),\\
\nabla f(x_2)(x_3-x_2) 
+ \frac1{2L} \|\nabla f(x_2) - \nabla f(x_3)\|^2
& \le f(x_3) - f(x_2),\\
\nabla f(x_3)(x_1-x_3) 
+ \frac1{2L} \|\nabla f(x_3) - \nabla f(x_1)\|^2
& \le f(x_1) - f(x_3),
\end{aligned}
$$
see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3217024/136544). For these gradients on the left-hand side we have
$$
\frac1{2L} \|\nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2)\|^2
+ \frac1{2L} \|\nabla f(x_2) - \nabla f(x_3)\|^2
+ \frac1{2L} \|\nabla f(x_3) - \nabla f(x_1)\|^2
\\
\ge \frac 3{4L} \|\nabla f(x_3) - \nabla f(x_1)\|^2.
$$
Proceeding as above, we get
$$
( \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2) ) (x_2-x_3)
+ \frac 3{4L} \|\nabla f(x_3) - \nabla f(x_1)\|^2 \\
\le (\nabla f(x_1) -\nabla f(x_3))(x_1-x_3) \\
\le \frac 3{4L} \|\nabla f(x_3) - \nabla f(x_1)\|^2  + \frac L3 \|x_1-x_3\|^2,
$$
which results in
$$
( \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2) ) (x_2-x_3)\le\frac L3 \|x_1-x_3\|^2.
$$
Still, not the correct constant. If $\|x_1-x_3\| \le \|\nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_3)\|$, i.e., $f$ is $1$-strongly convex, then we get the estimate with $L/4$ instead of $L/3$.

---

A lower bound of this quantity cannot be written in terms of $\|x_1-x_3\|$: take $f(x) = \frac12x^2$. Then for $x_2 \to +\infty$, the term in question tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: I suspect you can find a counterexample using $f(x) = (1/2)||x||^2$: we can assume w.l.o.g. that $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = a||x_1||$ for some scalar $a\geq0$, and the angle between $x_1$ and $x_3$ is $\theta$. In that case, the inner product becomes $-\langle x_1, x_3 \rangle=-a\cos(\theta) ||x_1||^2$; whereas, the upper bound in the inequality becomes $(((1-a\cos(\theta))^2 + (a\sin(\theta))^2)||x_1||^2/4$. And you can easily show that for any $a$ and $\theta$ we have $$-4a\cos(\theta)\leq ((1-a\cos(\theta))^2 + (a\sin(\theta))^2.$$Hence, the inequality in the question holds for arbitrary points.

Comment: If you have a working counterexample, can you write it explicitly? Otherwise, I will downvote your answer.

Comment: The above example has a typo; it should be $||x_3|| = a||x_1||$.

Comment: @Kurban: you are right, added a proof with constant $L$ instead of $L/4$ on the rhs.

Comment: I found the proof; please see my post.

Answer (score 0):

This inequality is used in A.S. Antipin's "On Finite Convergence of Processes to a Sharp Minimum and to a Smooth Minimum with a Sharp Derivative" paper, though I do not know the proof.

Comment: This is more like a comment.